# Trying to read an instance of an object into a database with PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, forms, dao

Hi I am trying to read an instance of my object person, take its individual details using a form, and then put it into a database. I think I have my code setting up the person, and connecting to the database ok, I just cant get it right when processing the information for the form, and reading it into the database. any help with be greatly appreciated!

my form

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form action="process.php" method="post">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" />
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" />
        Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
        <input type="submit" />
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

where I have my attempt at processing it

```
   <?php
$i = 0;
$firstName = 'firstName';
$lastName = 'lastName';
$age = 'age';
$person = new person ($i,$firstName, $lastName, $age);
$PersonDAO = new PersonDAO();
$dao->insert($person);
?>
```

my DAO

class PersonDAO extends Person{
    protected $link;

```
public function __construct() {
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "test";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database";

    $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $this->link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
}
public function __destruct() {
    $this->link = null;
}

public function insert($person){
    if (!isset($person) && $person != null){
        throw new Exception("Person Required");
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO person(firstName, lastName, age)"
    . "VALUES (:firstName, :lastName, :age)";

    $params = array(
        'firstName' => $person->getFirstName(),
        'lastName' => $person->getLastName(),
        'age' => $person->getAge(),
    );

    $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
    $status = $this->execute($params);
    if ($status != true){
        $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
        throw new Exception("Could Not Add Person: " . $errorInfo[2]);
    }

    $id = $this->link->lastInsertId('person');
    $person->setId($id);


    }
```

}
?>

my form comes up fine, but when i click submit it says
"Fatal error: Class 'person' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/personProj/process.php on line 6"

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
$person = new Person ($i,$firstName, $lastName, $age);
```

If the class is defined with a capital, you should call it with a capital letter as well. It's always a good idea to be consistent with the case of method/class calls. In many other languages like Java, this is very strict (although PHP can be loose about this rule in some cases).

Comment: @user1180888 Where is the class Person located on your filesystem? Have you remembered to write `require_once('/path/to/Person.php');` at the top of your Process.php script?

Comment: oh sweet, I think that sorted that. although now I am getting this error, any ideas?
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PersonDAO::execute() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/personProj/personDAO.php on line 35